# Thaana font on mobile web browsers

Tags: android, css, iphone, fonts, bidi

I'm working with fonts for a small language called Dhivehi (Maldivian). The alphabet is called "Thaana". There are a number of Unicode fonts available for it (such as Microsoft's MV Boli). It is written right-to-left.
While it appears perfectly on web browsers on laptops, it does not appear correctly on mobile-phone based browsers.

I'm using the following CSS code to apply the fonts:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Eamaan';
src: url('http://www.sun.mv/css/MvEamaanXP.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.thaana{direction:rtl; float:right; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;font-size:16pt;
                float: left;font-family:"Eamaan"; padding:2%;}
```

For my HTML, I'm using the following:

```
<p class="thaana">މިއީ ހަމަ ރަގަޅު ކަމެކެވެ</p>
```

And this produces legible writing on a web browser, however it doesn't work at all (for me) on any mobile-phone based browsers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mobile browsers often don't implement all features of desktop browsers. But you can render your text with images of charactes.

Comment: Which mobile browsers are you testing? Chrome for Android/iOS? iOS Safari? Opera? If you're testing on stock browsers on Android you may to into issues. Those are forked variations of WebKit implemented by the OEM. Also, check the features are supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=Font

Comment: Using just one font format is not enough. There are several old questions on the topic (answers might be a bit outdated).

Comment: @MattSmith, I've been trying it on Chrome and stock browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if the issue is the use of true-type fonts. Chrome (Blink) and WebKit browsers (Android stock) are supposed to support true-type, yet when I run this code in Chrome on my desktop I don't see Eamaan getting rendered.

[This site](http://www.haveeru.com.mv/dhivehi/business/126135) uses Waheed and they're using the open-type font version which renders in Chrome fine. If the open-type font of Eamaan is available in the URL of your `font-face` rule, I'd suggest adding it.

Example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Eamaan';
        src: url('http://www.sun.mv/css/MvEamaanXP.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('http://www.sun.mv/css/MvEamaanXP.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

You may want to expand it further to include `.eot`, `.woff`, and `.svg` for full support for `font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
        url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
        url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```